# How to lock the pull down menu / sound settings

Tags: lock-screens, 5.1-lollipop

I am using Android 5.1.1 on a Nexus 4.

When the screen is locked, I still can change the sound settings (mute, volume) and I can pull down the top screen menu with the settings for WLAN / Bluetooth, flashlight and so on.

Sometimes I do switch those settings accidentally when the phone is in my pocket, so the light goes on and the battery is finished fast.

How can I lock those settings?

Comment: Even with pattern lock is enabled for screen locking?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lollipop hide quick settings on Lock screen](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/112455/lollipop-hide-quick-settings-on-lock-screen)