# How to hide hotspot icon in the drop down after lock

Tags: wi-fi, 6.0-marshmallow, wifi-hotspot, notification-icons

Sir , I use android marshmallow and My brother always enables the hotspot also after I lock the Phone with Password 
Because "hotspot setting is shown in drop down menu "  I wanted to ask how to remove it ?
From dropdown menu after lock?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: See https://android.stackexchange.com/q/112455/96277

Answer (score 1):

For Android Marshmallow devices, you need to activate SystemUI Tuner which is hidden by default. 
To enable the SystemUI Tuner:

1. Swipe down the notification shade from top. Long-press the Settings(gear) icon.
2. After about few seconds of holding, it spins and release when it displays a message saying `Congrats! System UI Tuner has been added to Settings`.
3. To access it, go to Settings->System UI Tuner(scroll down to the bottom of the screen). Tap it.
4. On the System UI Tuner device shows a warning message. Tap `Got It` to continue.
5. Tap Quick Settings option to customize your tiles.

   a. Press and drag to rearrange

   b. Drag to the trash can to remove tiles you don’t want to see.

   c. Click "Add Tile" button to add any unused tiles you want to include.

   d. If you want to go back to the default layout, tap the menu button and choose “Reset”.

**Note:**

Choose option **5b** to Remove the Hotspot tile. After that, you can activate Hotspot only from Settings App, because, icon is no longer displayed under notification shade, until you add hotspot tile using add tile option.

Comment: please specify your device and model, because above settings are available mostly in stock android devices.(for device given in imgur screen shot, I think these settings are available. for any other devices there may be or may not  )

Comment: On my Android-6-devices, the QuickSettings have a special tile to modify what elements should be shown at all and in which order. But that might be ROM specific (here: LineageOS/CyanogenOS).